# Mostrar nome da url na página

Tags: django-templates, django-2.0

alguém sabe se da para capturar o nome da url na página?

tipo to querendo fazer uma condição para usar o class="active"
exemplo:

```
   {% if url 'create_indicador' %}
   <li class="active">.......
   {% else %}
   <li>........
   {% endif %}
```

desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui fazer assim tbm, pq esbarrei em um outro problema que quando tem na url depois da barra, tipo crete_indicator/people utilizando o == meu active não dava certo, ai no caso só verifico se a string contem dentro da request.path

funciona 100%!

```
{% if 'create_indicador' in request.path %}
<li class="active">.......
{% else %}
<li>........
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

O método get_full_path() devolve "metade" do endereço da página, ou melhor, devolve o endereço da sua página sem o domínio. Por exemplo, se o endereço for: http://www.site_exemplo.com.br/bla/ble/bli/ usar o request.get_full_path() em sua view retorna /bla/ble/bli/.
A grande questão era como obter a parte http://www.site_exemplo.com.br.

Como fazer isso?
Simples, é só utilizar o método build_absolute_uri() do objeto request de sua view. Pronto! Problema resolvido.

Comment: Edson boa noite, cara como que coloco isso no meu template?

pensei em fazer algo assim

ai no caso só to chutando como fica....

  {% if 'create_indicador/' is get_full_path() %}
   <li class="active">.......
   {% else %}
   <li>........
   {% endif %}

minha url 
path('create_indicator/', include('django.indicators.urls')),

Comment: Você já tentou fazer dessa sua maneira, parece funcionar.

Comment: Edson deu certo desse jeito
{% if '/create_indicador/' == request.path %}
<li class="active">.......
{% else %}
<li>........
{% endif %}

Answer (score -1):

Deu certo assim

```
{% if '/create_indicador/' == request.path %}
<li class="active">.......
{% else %}
<li>........
{% endif %}
```